# Flashing nRF9160 on a custom board with FTDI UART converter or nRF5340DK?

Tags: uart, programming, programmer, swd, nordic

I'm working on a custom board with nRF9160, I want to flash it with the asset tracker sample, however, I do not own a J-link device. What I have is a FTDI USB-UART converter, a nRF5340DK board, a ST-Link v2 programmer. Can I use any of these to flash my nRF9160 with the sample?

I have following pins exposed on my board:

- 3V3 SWDIO (Pin 34)
- SWCLK (Pin 33)
- RESET (Pin 32)
- UART RX (Pin 2)
- UART TX (Pin 3)
- Pin 20
- GND

I don't have any fancy connectors, such as these on nRF5340DK, just plain and simple jumper wires. Can I flash my nRF9160 with my current setup?

Answer (score 1):

It's been many years since I used nRF. So, don't get mad if I say wrong. :)
I remember I had to update the nRF device internal firmware, and the manufacturer's (Nordic) update procedure worked. I forgot what port I used, but it was not JTAG.

See if this link leads, as a starting point, to anywhere to your answer page: [Updating the modem firmware](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/ug_nrf91_dk_gsg/UG/nrf91_DK_gsg/updating_modem_firmware.html), [nRF9160_DK_Getting_Started_Guide](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF9160_DK_Getting_Started_Guide.pdf)